# Formating numbers with leading zeros in Blade view

Tags: laravel-5, number-formatting, laravel-blade

I have the following code in a Blade view:

```
@for ($i = 1; $i <= 99; $i++)
    <div id="player-{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</div>
@endfor
```

Which generates divs with ids player-1, player-2, player-3, etc. But what I really need is to have the ids player-01, player-02, player-03, etc. Is there a function in blade to do that like printf in PHP? or using a ternary operator is the best way around?

(The ternary operator works fine when only one zero needs to be added, but doesn't work that fine when more zeros are needed)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use str_pad($yourNumebr,$lengthOfYourNumber,$padString,$padType) to do this.

For more details  [click here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

```
@for ($i = 1; $i <= 99; $i++)
    <div id="player-{{ str_pad($i,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT) }}">{{ $i }}</div>
@endfor
```

Or

```
sprintf('%02d', $i);
```

Comment: using `sprintf` is about twice as fast as str_pad (php 7)

Comment: sprintf works in Blade? that's exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: Here is how I'm using it `@php(printf("%.2f", $num))`